# How do I http.get localhost

Tags: node.js, request, localhost

I am trying to fetch a page from port 1717 but when my bandwidth is unavailable, the http.get on error callback logs errno ENOENT whereas when I turn my bandwidth back on, it logs errno ECONNRESET. Regardless of my computer being offline or not, the url http://localhost:1717/admin/available/ ALWAYS returns content in the browser as long as the server is up and running. I've tried using postman and I have also tried using `request` method of the http module instead of `get`. I `end`ed request after using it but I still got the same errors.

Meanwhile I have tried getting other links besides those on localhost and it fetched them. In some other threads, I saw people suggest I use hostname 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. That too did not work so I switched to the request module from npm then there was a slight difference in behavior. In the server.js, I have sommething like this for GET requests hitting /admin/available/

```
            console.log('giving you table', table)
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            res.end(table);
```

However, when I use the request module, it throws the error ECONNRESET but in the CLI window where the server is running, this `console.log('giving you table', table)` is logged, meaning the server does see that request but somehow, the module still throws ECONNRESET and the body and response variables are undefined, claiming it cannot see it. What can I do about this?
I'll be posting my code below in case I'm missing something.

```
var http = require('http'),
component = require('../lib/render-component'),
render = {username: '', available: '', orders: '', frequent: ''}; 

// for simplicity
var request = require('request');
request('http://localhost:1717/admin/available',  function(err, res, body) {
    console.log(err, res, body)
});

// intended use scenario
http.get({port: 1717, path: '/admin/available/', headers: {Accept: 'text/html'}}, function(res) {
        var temp = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');

        console.log('inside get');

        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            temp += chunk;
        }).on('end', function() {
            render.available = temp;

            http.get('http://localhost:1717/admin/order/?page=0',  function(res) {

            var temp = ''
            res.setEncoding('utf8');

            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                temp += chunk;
            }).on('end', function() {
                render.orders = temp;

                ordersModel.find({status: 'delivered'}, 'food', function (err, orders) {
                if (err) throw err;

                var hashMap = [], returnArr = [];

                orders.forEach(function (order) {
                    hashMap.push(order.toObject()['food'].split(","));
                })

                hashMap.reduce(function(a, b) {
                    return a.concat(b)
                }, []).forEach(function(item) {

                    if ((k = returnArr.findIndex(function(elem) {
                        return elem[0] == item;
                    })) != -1) {
                        returnArr[k][1]++;
                    }
                    else returnArr.push([item, 1]);
                })

                // filter the ones with the highest value
                hashMap = [], returnArr = returnArr.sort(function(a, b) {
                    return b[1] - a[1];
                }).slice(0, 5).forEach(function(elem) {
                    hashMap.push({name: elem[0], counter: elem[1]})
                });

                render.frequent = component("frequent", hashMap);

                console.log(render)
            }) // orders model find
        }); // get orders
    }).on('error', function(e) {
            console.log(e)
        });
    }); // available on end

}).on('error', function(e) {
            console.log('err available', e)
    }); // available on error
```

Please help me. I've been stuck for three days now.

Comment: shouldn't you try something like express for server side and request for sending http requests between server-api that piece code looks terrible implementation of something that could be done with promises or use of an orm. Try producing more output though.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix does the problem have to do with code organization? If no resources are fetched, promises will still receive the error object. Besides, this is a proxy trying to batch fetch a series of resources, not the actual server itself. Do I still need express for that?